# How to get Reverse routing access at global.scala?

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

On global.scala, I initiallize some pictures address and write it into the database.
I want to get the path and address of picture address dynamically, since I do not want to rewrite the database string everytime.

for example how to get address

```
@routes.Assets.at(pic_url.getOrElse(default_server_pic))
```

in global.scala, what kind of headers I should import?

Answer (score 1):

The routes object is generated under the controllers package, so:

```
controllers.routes.Assets.at("something")
```